# Angularjs Karma suddenly not executing tests anymore

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am looking after a legacy Angularjs project and part of this project is Karma and Jasmin. Everything worked well so far, but without any (obvious) reason karma itself still starts up but does not execute any tests anymore. Instead of that it times out after 10000ms.

I would not have a clue how to debug that. Can anyone help?  Here is the Karma conf

"use strict";

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: './',
        files: [
            {pattern: 'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'app/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'app/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'app/bower_components/angularjs-datepicker/dist/angular-datepicker.min.js*', included: false},
            {pattern: 'app/app.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'app/**/*.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'app/**/*spec.js', included: false},

            // needs to be last http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/plus/requirejs.html
            'app/require-config.js'
        ],
        ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
            stripPrefix: 'public/',
            stripSuffix: '.ext',
            // prepend this to the
            prependPrefix: 'served/',
            moduleName: 'templates'
        },
        autoWatch: true,
        frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],
        plugins: [
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-firefox-launcher',
            'karma-ie-launcher',
            'karma-safari-launcher',
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-requirejs',
            'karma-junit-reporter',
            'karma-coverage',
            'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor',
            'karma-phantomjs-launcher'
        ],
        preprocessors: {
            'app/home/**/!(*spec)*.js': 'coverage',
            'app/navigation/**/!(*spec)*.js': 'coverage',
            'app/content/**/!(*spec)*.js': 'coverage',
            'app/alerts/**/!(*spec)*.js': 'coverage',
            'app/eco_login/**/!(*spec)*.js': 'coverage',
            'app/coms/**/!(*spec)*.js': 'coverage',
            'app/current_observations/**/!(*spec)*.js': 'coverage',
            'app/filters/**/!(*spec)*.js': 'coverage',
            'app/observation_records/**/!(*spec)*.js': 'coverage',
            'app/script_writer/**/!(*spec)*.js': 'coverage',
            'app/script_guidance/**/!(*spec)*.js': 'coverage',
            'app/databrowser/**/!(*spec)*.js': 'coverage',
            'app/eco/**/!(*spec)*.js': 'coverage',
            'app/extremes/**/!(*spec)*.js': 'coverage',
            'app/services/**/!(*spec)*.js': 'coverage',
            'app/location_data/**/!(*spec)*.js': 'coverage',
            'app/location_picker/**/!(*spec)*.js': 'coverage',
            'app/location_map/**/!(*spec)*.js': 'coverage',
            'app/text_forecast/**/!(*spec)*.js': 'coverage',
            'app/**/*.html': ["ng-html2js"]
        },
        coverageReporter: {
            reporters: [
                {
                    type: 'cobertura',
                    dir: 'coverage/',
                    subdir: function (browser) {
                        // normalization process to keep a consistent browser name across different
                        // OS
                        return browser.replace(/ /g, '_');
                    }
                },
                {
                    type: 'lcovonly',
                    dir: 'coverage/',
                    subdir: function (browser) {
                        // normalization process to keep a consistent browser name across different
                        // OS
                        return browser.replace(/ /g, '_');
                    }
                },
                {
                    type: 'html',
                    dir: 'coverage/',
                    subdir: function (browser) {
                        // normalization process to keep a consistent browser name across different
                        // OS
                        return browser.replace(/ /g, '_');
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        browserConsoleLogOptions: {
            terminal: true,
            level: ""
        },
        // test results reporter to use
        // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
        // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
        reporters: ['progress', 'coverage', 'junit'],
        junitReporter: {
            outputDir: 'coverage/',
            outputFile: 'unit.xml',
            suite: 'unit'
        },
        noColors: true,
        captureConsole: true,
        logLevelDebug: true,
        singleRun: true,
        logLevel: 'debug',
        browsers: ['Firefox']
    });
};
```

I set the logLevelDebug to true, this is part of the output

```
18 04 2017 08:10:07.695:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.6.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
    18 04 2017 08:10:07.696:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Firefox with unlimited concurrency
18 04 2017 08:10:07.707:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Firefox
18 04 2017 08:10:07.708:DEBUG [temp-dir]: Creating temp dir at /tmp/karma-17509431
18 04 2017 08:10:07.709:DEBUG [launcher]: firefox http://localhost:9876/?id=17509431 -profile /tmp/karma-17509431 -no-remote
    18 04 2017 08:10:09.620:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /home/uwe/ws/ForecasterPortal/node_modules/karma/static/client.html
18 04 2017 08:10:09.950:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /home/uwe/ws/ForecasterPortal/node_modules/karma/static/karma.js
18 04 2017 08:10:10.174:DEBUG [karma]: A browser has connected on socket NeEdoBJw1Olt5Vk5AAAA
18 04 2017 08:10:10.183:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /home/uwe/ws/ForecasterPortal/node_modules/karma/static/favicon.ico
18 04 2017 08:10:10.276:INFO [Firefox 52.0.0 (Ubuntu 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket NeEdoBJw1Olt5Vk5AAAA with id 17509431
18 04 2017 08:10:10.277:DEBUG [launcher]: Firefox (id 17509431) captured in 2.581 secs
18 04 2017 08:10:10.278:DEBUG [web-server]: upgrade /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=NeEdoBJw1Olt5Vk5AAAA
    18 04 2017 08:10:10.320:DEBUG [middleware:karma]: custom files null null null
18 04 2017 08:10:10.322:DEBUG [middleware:karma]: Serving static request /context.html
18 04 2017 08:10:10.337:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /home/uwe/ws/ForecasterPortal/node_modules/karma/static/context.html
18 04 2017 08:10:10.394:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /home/uwe/ws/ForecasterPortal/node_modules/karma/static/context.js
18 04 2017 08:10:10.396:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/requirejs/require.js?b1010092f15879164973aaba0cc26c7298118d76 /
    18 04 2017 08:10:10.396:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /home/uwe/ws/ForecasterPortal/node_modules/requirejs/require.js
18 04 2017 08:10:10.397:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/uwe/ws/ForecasterPortal/node_modules/requirejs/require.js
18 04 2017 08:10:10.399:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/adapter.js?a0765fc3eacb39184893303c3bc2e821cb041787 /
    18 04 2017 08:10:10.403:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /home/uwe/ws/ForecasterPortal/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/adapter.js
18 04 2017 08:10:10.404:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/uwe/ws/ForecasterPortal/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/adapter.js
18 04 2017 08:10:10.430:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?916005cc407925f4764668d61d04888d59258f5d /
    18 04 2017 08:10:10.430:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /home/uwe/ws/ForecasterPortal/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js
18 04 2017 08:10:10.431:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js?945a38bf4e45ad2770eb94868231905a04a0bd3e /
    18 04 2017 08:10:10.431:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /home/uwe/ws/ForecasterPortal/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js
18 04 2017 08:10:10.431:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js?7a813cc290d592e664331c573a1a796192cdd1ad /
    18 04 2017 08:10:10.432:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /home/uwe/ws/ForecasterPortal/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
18 04 2017 08:10:10.432:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/uwe/ws/ForecasterPortal/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js
18 04 2017 08:10:10.436:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/uwe/ws/ForecasterPortal/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js
18 04 2017 08:10:10.437:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/uwe/ws/ForecasterPortal/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
18 04 2017 08:10:20.283:WARN [Firefox 52.0.0 (Ubuntu 0.0.0)]: Disconnected (1 times), because no message in 10000 ms.
    Firefox 52.0.0 (Ubuntu 0.0.0) ERROR
Disconnected, because no message in 10000 ms.
```

Comment: Looks like something in the latest Karma does not like my project. I chose an earlier version (1.1.1)  and the test are running again.

Comment: I would still love to understand why it stopped working.